# Determine whether object-wrapped primitive was user created

Tags: javascript, primitive

```
var obj = {x:5, y:new Number(5)};

function value(value) {
    //using == would result in false positives for value.call(obj.y, new Number(5));
    return this === value;
}

console.log(value.call(obj.x, obj.x)); //False
console.log(value.call(obj.y, obj.y)); //True
```

Javascript (for obvious reasons), wraps primitives in temporary objects when they are assigned to `this`.  Are there any ways to determine whether the object referenced via `this` is user-created and permanent vs. system-created and transient?

Comment: Are you sure it is JavaScript not Java ?

Comment: @Max, perhaps boxing isn't the correct term within Javascript - I'm referring to Object wrappers around Primitive types.

Comment: Why not treat them equally instead?

Comment: Perhaps this [page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp) will help you with the JavaScript types

Comment: @Max, this isn't really a question about types: http://jsfiddle.net/nwye5r5a/

Comment: @zerkms, that would be the obvious resolution to something like this, that or just not using ```this``` in the first place. I'm just curious if there are any tools in the language to accommodate a full-fledged solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
function fun() {
    // in browser, the 'global' is window, and global in node.
    // but in strict mode, if you don't specify 'this', it will be 'undefined'.
    if (this === global || this === undefined) {
        console.log('system created');
    } else {
        console.log('user created');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is applicable.  Javascript allows primitives to be passed as the context of ```call()``` and ```apply()```.  When this happens, ```this``` will never be global or undefined, it will be a wrapped version of the primitive passed in.

Comment: @danShumway  sorry, I misunderstand your words. I think there is no way to determine this.